# CSS linter detecting if selector was used in document

Tags: css, syntax

I am using css linter for sublime that detects syntax errors.

Is there any linter that would scan html document and check if selector has corresponding DOM elements?

That would help with eliminating typos with classes and IDs.

Comment: did you ever resolve your issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any CSS lint tools that check for unused rules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644644/are-there-any-css-lint-tools-that-check-for-unused-rules)

Answer (score 2):

I dont believe that there are any sublime text plugins that curently do this, however there are several grunt tools that can do this, so an otion is:

1. use the [grunt-sublime plugin](https://github.com/tvooo/sublime-grunt) to run grunt tasts through sublime
2. set up a grunt job to use something like [uncss](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss) to find css selectors you dont need
3. run the task with [grunt watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) so that the css check is done on file save

You'll get the output throguh sublime so you know if you have added a css selector that isnt in your html